# Choosing the correct way to call function in stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i am having tough time figuring/understanding the correct way to call method inside a class in javascript for example

consider we have stateful component with various method like

```
addIngredientHandler = (type) => { //Adds one to the state of ingredient }
```

and

```
purchasingHandlerOpen =  () =>   this.setState({purchasing: true}) //will show a order summary pop-up if we have more than one ingredient
```

We pass both of them to child component (using props) by calling them in a return of our stateful component like this

```
  <BuildControls           
       ingredientAdded={this.addIngredientHandler} 
       purchasingHandlerOpen={this.purchasingHandlerOpen}
       purchasableHandler={this.state.purchasable} />
```

and In our stateless child component we do

```
<BuildControl
       ingredientAdded={() => props.ingredientAdded(el.type)}
      />))}
      <button className={Classes.OrderButton} disabled={!props.purchasableHandler} onClick={props.purchasingHandlerOpen}>Order</button>
  </div
```

Here we have use this at one place

```
 ingredientAdded={() => props.ingredientAdded(el.type)}
```

and this in another

```
onClick={props.purchasingHandlerOpen}>
```

**So my question** is when do we call a method/function using `{() => props.ingredientAdded(el.type)}` and when do we use `{props.purchasingHandlerOpen}` and when do we probably do something like `{props.purchasingHandlerOpen()}`

Slight Note: In the above example where i do

```
<button className={Classes.OrderButton} disabled={!props.purchasableHandler} onClick={props.purchasingHandlerOpen}>Order</button>
```

If I do something like `{props.purchasingHandlerOpen()}` it throws infinite render error message, I I do something like `{() => props.purchasingHandlerOpen}` the button does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that the thing you're passing here are just functions, so there is **nothing principally different** in those 2 ways

There are few points you need to consider though:

First: since react.js uses shallow comparison, every time you're passing

```
ingredientAdded={() => props.ingredientAdded(el.type)}
```

you're actually pass function created just now, so it may cause unneeded calls of your children `render` function (you could easily avoid this by using `shouldComponentUpdate` though). This could lead to possible performance issues on big react trees so that you second approach is preferred.

Second: you could easily mix a some value via your first approach, something like

```
ingredientAdded={() => props.ingredientAdded(el.type, SOMETHING_FROM_STATE)}
```

Third. You can easily modify your event handlers and pass down them in react tree by generating functions which return functions:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  generateFunction(something) {
    return (arg) => {
      this.props.myFunction(something, arg)
    }
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <FirstComponent onClick={this.generateClickFunction('First')} />
       <SecondComponent onClick={this.generateClickFunction('Second')} />
     </div>
   }
  }
}
```

**UPD**

`onClick` should always receive function, not its results, like that:

```
<button ... onClick={props.purchasingHandlerOpen} />
```

if you are changing `onClick` to `{props.purchasingHandlerOpen()}` you are calling the function, so you're passing its result to props.

If you are changing `onClick` to `{() => purchasingHandlerOpen}` you are passing undefined (it's not a `props.purchasingHandlerOpen`, but `purchasingHandlerOpen` is undefined) so that React considers there is no a callback passed to the props

Comment: When you say **nothing principally different**. I take it as they both are same? so In the `<button className={Classes.OrderButton} disabled={!props.purchasableHandler} onClick={props.purchasingHandlerOpen}>` if I change the onClick to `{props.purchasingHandlerOpen()}` , it throws an error for infinite render and if I use `{() => purchasingHandlerOpen}` the button does not work. can you explain the reason for the same?

Comment: Take a look at UPD. I placed explanation there

Comment: Perfect answer, Thanks. Just one more thing suppose we have `postClicked = (id) => {
    this.setState({selectedPostId: id})
  }` in our react stateful component, In render if we do something like `onClick={this.postClicked(el.id)}` we get infinite loop error but if we do `onClick={() => this.postClicked(el.id)}` it works as expected so what is the difference between both? why does both of them work differently?

Answer (score -1):

`{() => props.ingredientAdded(el.type)}` creates a new funciton which binds the `el.type`, see [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

`{props.purchasingHandlerOpen}` does nothing since we do not execute the function (there are no `(), call, apply`). We simply pass the function reference.

`{props.purchasingHandlerOpen()}` runs the function.